# how to add and remove a class from a list of li elements?

Tags: jquery

if i have an li list like this:

```
<ul>
<li>first </li>
<li>second</li>
<li>third</li>
<li>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

How would i write the code in jquery to add a class to the li element , say , first without the class being added to the others?

i tried this but it of course adds to all li elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("ul li").click(function() {
if(!$("ul li").hasClass('active'))
{
$("ul li").addClass('active');
}
});

});
```

i want to be able to add the class active to only the li element that was click and remove all other exists who have active added to them. how would i do this? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this); // reference to the clicked li
  if(!$this.hasClass('active'))
  {
    $this.addClass('active');
    $('ul li').not($this).removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb9yx/

Another way

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this); // reference to the clicked li
  if(!$this.hasClass('active'))
  {
    $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/d5Sde/

This one one of those ones where there's probably a hundred ways to achieve the same thing.